# UIScrollView: Animation banner effect

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiscrollview, transition

I have an UIScrollView with a PageControl, that show some pictures inside the view.

I'd like to create an animation, like a banner effect that changes the image after X seconds automatically.

- Can do this with UIScrollView or should I use another way?

**EDIT: @selector**

```
- (void) changePage:(UIPageControl *)sender
{
    if ([pageControl currentPage]  < 3) {

        [pageControl setCurrentPage:[pageControl currentPage] + 1];
    } else{
        [pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView is fine.
You have to set pagingEnabled on the scrollView and after a certain time, change the page selected on the scrollView.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know how to setpagingEnabled, but how to set the time to change the page selected?

Comment: there are many ways: with NSTimer or with [self performSelector@selector(changePage) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

Comment: with  [self performSelector@selector(changePage) withObject:nil afterDelay:3]; it just change one time and stop.

Comment: Yes, has expected! Have a look at + (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats

Comment: Thanks, it is working for the pageControl, I just dont know how to set the image on ScrollView to be displayed when pageControl changes. I just put the @selector in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, pagingEnabled changes current position as a page.

Change `pageControl.pagingEnabled`  into `pageControl.scrollEnabled`

Answer (score 0):

`scrollEnabled` : Scrolls like x/y axis as you scroll

`pagingEnabled` : Scrolls like current scroll view as a page for each scroll.

Now replace your  `pagingEnabled` into `scrollEnabled`.